# How to link a theme to a map layout in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layouts, mapping, theme

I have different map layouts In QGIS which use different map themes. Currently, I have to choose a theme first before opening its corresponding map layout. Is there a way to link a theme to a map layout, so that whenever I open a map layout, its theme will be turned on and the map layout is showing what are desired automatically?

Comment: Do you mean activate the theme in the print layout only or also in the main map view of QGIS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but after creating your layout, adding your map item, you can assign the theme to always use it using in "Item Properties" tab, within the section "Layers", the checkbox "Follow map theme" and associated combo box.

After saving, next time, you will open the layout, you will already get the "right" theme. See below screen capture to do so. Or maybe your question is about doing it magically!?

[image: Set a specific theme for a map item in QGIS layout]

Comment: Thank you. this is what I need.